# Subtheme: How to use the template function of a parent theme (from inside the parent theme)

Tags: theming

I have created a theme that contains several functions.

I now want to create a sub theme. That way, I can use the parent theme on all my sites (and any updates to the parent the theme can be easily applied to all the sites). The sub theme will contain all the modifications that are specific to that individual website.

I have created a sub theme following the instructions in [this tutorial](https://drupal.org/node/225125). When I enable the subtheme, the site breaks. Most of the content disappears and I get this error message:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function `legendary_views_field_compare_value()` in /all/themes/legendary/templates/slideshow.tpl.php on line 20

- `legendary_views_field_compare_value()` is the name of a function in my
  parent theme.
- legendary is the name of my parent theme.
- slideshow.tpl.php is a template in my parent theme.

I don't understand why this is happening. I thought the sub theme should inherit all the functions of the parent theme (especially is the function is being called from inside the parent theme and NOT in the sub theme).

How can I fix this?

Comment: Where did you define the function? I suppose that you did it in the template.php

Comment: @Rufein  Yes, the function is defined in template.php in the parent theme and is called from a template file inside of the parent theme.

Comment: I have a suggestion. The instructions that you have been following warn that _There are two main types of functions in template.php: theme function overrides and preprocess functions_ . Taking a look to the theme.inc, i've found this function ´drupal_find_theme_functions()´, that uses the cache to store the hooks defined in your themes and modules. So, i am wondering that Drupal only load the template.php when the the result is true in that function. A solution: you separate the custom function in a file, for example ´myfiles.inc´ and add in the .info theme that file

Comment: @Rufein would `myfiles.inc` go in the theme directory. Also how do you a reference an Inc file in a .info file. I've looked at this tutorial about .info files, but it doesn't say how to add inc files in an info file. Thanks for any help you can offer.

Comment: You are right, the theme .info doesn't support files[] directive, i was thinking in module .info. But don't worry there are more ways to load files. For example, i would use a preproccess function to load the file with include_once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### **The problem**

Pay attention to your first sentence:

> I have created a theme that contains several functions.

The link that you have provided warns about what type of functions hold a `template.php` in a theme.

> There are two main types of functions in template.php: **theme function
>   overrides** and **preprocess functions**. The template system handles these
>   two types in very different ways.

Is legendary_views_field_compare_value() any of these cases? OK, we agree that the anwers is **No**. It's a custom function that you have written.

***Why should not you put your custom functions in `template.php`?***

Because Drupal has a registry of implemented hooks and templates that have been overriden. The system only load the `template.php` when match the hook in the registry. So, the `template.php` is not always load.

### **The solution**

First of all, you should keep separate the custom functions from the theme functions. You need to create a file called for example `my_custom_functions.inc` , and insert all your custom functions in that file.

***How do i load a file with custom functions that i need to call in my templates?***

To keep separate the logic from the theme functions, i would stored the custom functions in a module. But, it is also possible store the functions in your theme. In both cases, you have to follow the next strategy.

It's really easy. Every time that a template is rendered, a preprocess function is fired by default to let other modules to act. So, it is always fired a preprocess (and process) function before the slideshow.tpl,php. In this moment, we will load the file with our custom functions.

Here an example:

```
/*
 *  Implements hook_preprocess_slideshow()
 *
 *  The file will load  before rendering slideshow.tpl.php
 */
 function NAME_OF_YOUR_THEME_preprocess_slideshow(&$variables){

     include_once 'my_custom_functions.inc';
 }
```

Please, pay attention to the name of the template. In my simulation, i have changed the template called `views-slideshow.tpl.php` . So, when you implements in hook_preprocess_HOOK(&$vars) , you need to change the hyphens. The result would be `NAME_OF_YOUR_THEME_preprocess_views_slideshow(&$vars)`

If you have to load the same file with custom functions in lots of templates, you could implement the general `hook_preprocess($vars)`, that it is always fired. Here an example:

```
 /*
 *  Implements hook_preprocess()
 *
 *  The system always load the file
 */
 function NAME_OF_YOUR_THEME_preprocess(&$variables){

     include_once 'my_function.inc';
 }
```

Comment: Where does My-fucntion.inc go? Does it go in the theme directory? Thanks for any help you can offer.

Comment: Yes, it should be in the same directory of template.php

Comment: Thanks for your help. But it doesn't seem to work. I am actually calling the function from inside multiple templates of the parent theme (including Views templates). I've tried adding it to mytheme_preprocess_page, mytheme_preprocess_html, but it still doesn't work. Thanks for any help you can offer.

Comment: I forgot: you have to clean the cache. Don´t add it in the preprocces of page or html, because hey are the last templates to be rendered in the whole proccess, so when these preproccess functions have been called,the slideshow has been rendered before

Comment: How can I add it so it available to multiple node.tpl.php and Views templates files. If I use theme_preprocess_slideshow, it won't be available to everything. Thanks for any help you can offer.

Comment: Is it working? If it's working and you want to be available in a lot of templates, the fastest way is implement `hook_preprocess(vars)`, that is a generic hook that is always called  before render a template.

Comment: It works if I just enable the parent theme. However, when I enable the sub theme, I get the same Fatal Error message. The templates that call the function are views functions (e.g. `views-view-fields--refine-slideshow.tpl.php`, `views-view-fields--call-to-action-node.tpl.php`). I have tried using `function legendary_preprocess(&$variables){
     include_once 'legendaryfunctions.inc';
 }` inside template.php and cleaning the cache.

Comment: I've done a simulation. First i have created a Parent theme based on Bartik and a child Theme. I have set the child theme as default theme. The functions on my template in the parent template.php haven been called and the include file is loaded. So, I guarantee you that this way to load the file is fine. Maybe there are a misspelled name.

Comment: Are you using hook_preprocess(vars)? Any chance you could use something like http://www.filedropper.com/ to upload your parent and child themes. Thanks for any help you can offer!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11954/discussion-between-rufein-and-big-smile)

Comment: Storing the function in a custom module fixed everything. Hope that helps someone.